# Prestashop hook actionProductUpdate get current available stock

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I developed a module which sync the product data to an external system.
So I implemented the actionProductUpdate hook. In this hook I try to get current available quantity. The problem is, that it seems that the hook is called before the update is commited to the database.

With following line I try to get the current quantity.

```
$productQuantity = StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct($productId);
```

The code works but it returns the old value. If I have 15 as quantity in the product, and I change it to 16... then 15 will be returned.
Can I use another hook? Or how can I get the current quantity.
Thx
Bernhard

Comment: I found a solution. The hook hookActionUpdateQuantity is the correct one to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try with hook :

```
actionObjectUpdateAfter() or actionObjectProductUpdateAfter()
```

Regards